# XML styled with XSL not displaying value but variable string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Style.xslt"?>
<AdditionalInfo>
    <Headers>
        <Header Text="Sys. Ref.">SysRef</Header>
        <Header Text="Doc. Ref.">DocRef</Header>
        <Header Text="Value">Value</Header>
    </Headers>
    <Lines>
        <Line>
            <SysRef>1234</SysRef>
            <DocRef>IN-1234</DocRef>
            <Value>123.45</Value>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <XYZ>aaa</XYZ>
            <SysRef>1234</SysRef>
            <DocRef>IN-1234</DocRef>
            <Value>123.45</Value>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

I need the following XML to transform to like below

```
Sys. Ref.     Doc. Ref.       Value
1234          IN-1234         123.45  
1234          IN-1234         123.45
```

But it is transforming into

```
Sys. Ref.     Doc. Ref.       Value
Sysref        DocRef          Value
```

Which is why I have come to see if there is some kind soul who knows what I did wrong. I know that it most likely involves the for each that I have done but I have tried over and over and this was the closest I got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:template match="Headers">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AdditionalInfo">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Additional Information</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold;">    Details</span>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <table style="width:700px;font:sans-seriff;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Headers"/>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Lines/Line">
                                <tr>

                                    <xsl:for-each select="../../Headers/Header">
            <xsl:variable name="headertext" select="."/>
                                        <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="../../Lines/Line">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$headertext"/>
                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @MathiasMüller so you are telling me to copy the resultcode directly from the browser

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this. Could you show us what is the **actual** expected result, based on the provided input? I am particularly puzzled by the XYZ element in the second line: is it to be included in the table? If yes, where?

Comment: @MathiasMüller CTRL+U in Firefox just shows the xml I passed

Comment: @michael.hor257k the xyz happens to be a case of data which is not supposed to be loaded

Comment: I have added the required result and what is being returned

Comment: It seems to me that you want to achieve some kind of grouping. Associate the names  of the elements with the contents of the `Header` tags. Print the `@Text` of the header tags as a table header, and print the corresponding values (`SysRef`, `DocRef` and `Value`) in their appropriate columns, and lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a radically different approach. Here's the no-frills example of it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="headers" select="/AdditionalInfo/Headers/Header"/>
<xsl:variable name="rows" select="/AdditionalInfo/Lines/Line"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="@Text"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="$rows">
            <xsl:variable name="rowNum" select="position()"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$rows[$rowNum]/*[name()=current()]"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AdditionalInfo>
    <Headers>
        <Header Text="Sys. Ref.">SysRef</Header>
        <Header Text="Doc. Ref.">DocRef</Header>
        <Header Text="Value">Value</Header>
    </Headers>
    <Lines>
        <Line>
            <SysRef>1234</SysRef>
            <DocRef>IN-1234</DocRef>
            <irrelevant>bbb</irrelevant>
            <Value>123.45</Value>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <XYZ>aaa</XYZ>
            <SysRef>4567</SysRef>
            <DocRef>IN-4567</DocRef>
            <Value>45.67</Value>
        </Line>
       <Line>
            <SysRef>8901</SysRef>
            <ignore>ccc</ignore>
            <Value>8.91</Value>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Sys. Ref.</th>
         <th>Doc. Ref.</th>
         <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1234</td>
         <td>IN-1234</td>
         <td>123.45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>4567</td>
         <td>IN-4567</td>
         <td>45.67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>8901</td>
         <td/>
         <td>8.91</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: when I run it, renders on 1 line.

Comment: @micheal.hor257k i got it working by adding <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

Comment: thank you very much for your help and I have now added the frills back my self. Which wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Writing separate templates greatly simplifies the task. A few remarks:

- any namespaces (xs and fn) are excluded in the output
- you should set "html" as the output method if your indeed outputting HTML
- are you sure that the XSLT version should be "2.0"? What kind of browser would support that?
- your header row is not really a header in the output HTML. You could put it inside a `thead` element

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Headers">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AdditionalInfo">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Additional Information</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold;">    Details</span>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <table style="width:700px;font:sans-seriff;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Headers"/>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Lines"/>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Lines">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SysRef|DocRef|Value">
        <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML output**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Additional Information</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div style="margin-top:20px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">    Details</span></div><br><table style="width:700px;font:sans-seriff;">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">Sys. Ref.</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">Doc. Ref.</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">Value</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">1234</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">IN-1234</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">123.45</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">1234</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">IN-1234</td>
                  <td style="border-top:1px double #D4D4D4;border-bottom:1px double #D4D4D4;border-right:1px double #D4D4D4;">123.45</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered Output**

> [image]

Comment: When I put the word SysRef it loads the actual XML value which is what I want shown.

Comment: `not(name() = 'XYZ')` Big assumption there.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Is there a way to select according to the headers?

Comment: @Enzero What do you mean by that?

Comment: `<xsl:template match="SysRef|DocRef|Value">` That's practically the same thing, just from a different angle. IMHO, this needs to be entirely data-driven - and I suspect that's what OP means by "select according to the headers".

Comment: I see. @Enzero yes that is possible - michael.hor257k has already given an answer to this.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I meant according to the data in the XML for Header Elements. As michael.hor257k said it has to be data-driven. Since I won't know what headers could be passed.